# CORS - Faking a CORS preflight from Postman fails to return headers

Tags: rest, http, cors, postman

If I fake an OPTIONS preflight CORS request from Postman, I don't get the CORS headers back from my API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to get it working using [Postman Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en)
The settings I had were as below [image: screenshot of my postman setup]

Comment: When you install the interceptor you need to activate it from the postman application (this is the first icon on top right on the screenshot above). After that I was able to pass by the CORS restriction.

Answer (score 18):

After completely reverse engineering the Microsoft.Owin.Cors library I discovered that the headers weren't on the request!

Which led me to this beauty from the Postman docs:

> Restricted headers and cookies
>
> Unfortunately some headers are restricted by Chrome and the
>   XMLHttpRequest specification. The following headers are blocked:
>
> Accept-Charset Accept-Encoding Access-Control-Request-Headers
>   Access-Control-Request-Method Connection Content-Length Cookie Cookie
>   2 Content-Transfer-Encoding Date Expect Host Keep-Alive Origin Referer
>   TE Trailer Transfer-Encoding Upgrade User-Agent Via

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests

Aaaaargh. That's a day of my life I won't get back.

Comment: Using [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) on Mac OS Mavericks (10.9.2) allowed me to test OPTIONS requests. *reference [Access-Control-Max-Age](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age) when setting up server

Comment: The answer below claims that they can do preflight response with use of the postman interceptor is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

I had to check a problem of preflight requests cut by firewall in production environment. I used the Postman to sent the OPTIONS requests. This article explains which headers you must set in OPTIONS request https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request . In my case I added: Origin, Referer, Access-Control-Request-Method and Access-Control-Request-Headers. If you miss some required headers the response returns 405 Method Not Allowed. If all is set correctly the response is 204 No Content and in headers you will find headers Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Headers. These headers are used by browser to confirm that preflight request is accepted and browser can send main request. [image: Postman OPTIONS query]