# Angular 4: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have created the WEBAPI and trying to access the web api post method from Angular 4 application getting the following error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:61611/api/Employees' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

And i am able to get the result from postman for api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check)

Comment: No, This is bit different i am getting this issue between angular 4 application and web api.

Comment: There is no difference indeed, and that's not related to angular neither to web api. it is a common issue once trying to invoke webservices from a localhost source (which is not a trusted source by default) -> CORS

Comment: Also related (re Postman): https://stackoverflow.com/q/36250615/1579626, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34931194/1579626, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36554935/1579626

Answer (score 0):

We need to mention the following code in `webapiconfig.cs`

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

After adding this code i am able to connect webapi from my angular application

Comment: File `webapiconfig.cs` is already exist or I need to create it